# Why the new capacity of arraylist is (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1?

Tags: java, arraylist

Why does ensureCapacity() in Java ArrayList extend the capacity with a const 1.5 or (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1?

Comment: It somewhere between growing a lot e.g. `* 2`, and a little `+ 1`

Comment: Exactly as above. Also, there is no real reason why `3/2` is better than `17/53` or `1.74`, they just chose a number between 1 and 2 which was easy to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason lies the (asymptotic) complexity of adding a sequence of elements to the list.

Note that the `add` method internally calls `ensureCapacity(size+1)`. When the size of the internal array is increased, all elements have to be *copied* into the new, larger array.

If the size was only increased by a constant *amount* (which would be 1 for each call to `add`), then adding **n** elements would have a complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Instead, the size is always increased by a constant *factor*. Then, adding **n** elements only has a complexity of **O(n)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I understand it from your answer!

Comment: Good that you have the O(n) vs O(n^2) part, which is really important!

Answer (score 6):

Resizing the array is a relatively expensive operation. It wants to try and make sure that if the method gets called with `ensureCapacity(11)`, `ensureCapacity(12)`, `ensureCapacity(13)`, ... it should not have to resize the array every time. So it resizes by a reasonable chunk (increase by 50%) instead of the minimum specified.

Comment: I'm a little understand about it,Thanks for your answer!